# PropertyChanged is not fired from a class in a different assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, fody-propertychanged

I have a class library with a base class (`BaseViewModel`) that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and a class that derive from it (`TestExternal`).

I use Fody v4.2.1 and PropertyChanged.Fody v2.6.1.

In the WPF app, I use that class as DataContext. When a property is changed, it is not reflected in the app. However, if I copy (and rename to `TestInternal`) that class from the class library to the app, property changes are reflected in the app. The class `TestInternal` is derived from the very same `BaseViewModel` in the class library.

The class in this simplified example consists of a `string`and `ObservableCollection<string>`.

The `ObservableCollection<string>` is bound to a control, and adding the element `"d"` is reflected correctly in the app in both cases. But setting the string property to `"C"` is only reflected in the `TestInternal` class.

What do I need to do to get this working?

### BaseViewModel.cs

```
// This class is in the class library
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

### TestExternal.cs

```
// This class is in the class library
public class TestExternal : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> UserProjects { get; set; }
    public string TestProp { get; set; }
    System.Windows.Application App;

    public TestExternal(System.Windows.Application app)
    {
        this.App = app;
        UserProjects = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
        TestProp = "A";

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            App.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                TestProp = "C";
                UserProjects.Add("d");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

### TestInternal.cs

```
// This class is in the WPF app project
public class TestInternal : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> UserProjects { get; set; }

    public string TestProp { get; set; }

    System.Windows.Application App;

    public TestInternal(System.Windows.Application app)
    {
        this.App = app;
        UserProjects = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
        TestProp = "A";

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            App.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                TestProp = "C";
                UserProjects.Add("d");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TestProp}" Style="{StaticResource NaviHeading}" />
```

Comment: Do you have a Weavers entry for your external lib project?
<Weavers><PropertyChanged></Weavers>
https://github.com/Fody/Home/blob/master/pages/usage.md#add-fodyweaversxml

Comment: @MichaelG Wow, simple as that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Fody to inject into the external assembly, you have to specify the appropriate weavers.

To indicate what weavers run and in what order a FodyWeavers.xml file is used at the project level. It needs to be added manually. It takes the following form:

```
<Weavers>
    <PropertyChanged />
</Weavers>
```

See https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged#add-to-fodyweaversxml